# How do I land three rockets within one second?

Tags: achievements, farpoint

I'm trying to get the Rocket Ranger trophy, which requires me to hit an enemy with three rockets within a second. It sounded pretty simple, but I can't seem to get it. If I try to do it from up-close, I die from the splash damage. However, if I stand further back, the rockets don't seem to hit within a second.

Is there some specific way I should be trying to do this? Also, I'm working under the assumption that the rockets I need to use are the alt-fire for the assault rifle, in case that's not what I'm supposed to be using.

Comment: [Git Gud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMGQ9.png)